# is there a way to prevent event triggering on input date when user hits up down arrow key?

Tags: html, date, input

[Text]I want to prevent event triggering on up/down arrow key so that I can select dates across the months. As soon as user hits arrow key it triggers an event.

Comment: Okay whats the problem. As long as there is no eventListener to it? What the actual issue?

Comment: Issue is when user hits up/down arrow from calendar it takes date of previous month ex. if I open calendar it will show 23/02/2021 and when I hit up arrow key it takes 23/01/2021 and calendar gets closed.

Comment: okay so that means there is an event listener bound to this event. Is there a URL you can share?? that would be good to see whats going on.